# Invoking action when bean destroyed

Tags: jsf, destructor, javabeans

I have a Bean that runs some threads with database connections. What can I do to make sure those connections are closed when the user navigates away? Can I define some form of "destructor" for JSF beans?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`@PreDestroy`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html) annotation is what you're looking for.